# Lotus Notes and xul files

Tags: xul, lotus-notes

How can I open [xul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL) forms in Lotes Notes (8.5.2)? I read [this](http://wolfgang.schmidetzki.net/blog/archives/22004/using_lotus_notes_to_develop_xul_applications.int.html), but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfgang's post shows how to *generate* a XUL form blending in data from a Lotus Notes database.  You can create a `Page` in Notes and insert any text content that you'd like output to a browser.  In this case the content-type of the page is set to **application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml**

When that Notes database is on a Domino server, and you visit that page in your browser, you will be opening a XUL form.  Since XUL only works on Mozilla-based browsers (i.e Firefox 3.5), other browsers will prompt you to download the content.  When you do visit with the Mozilla browser you'll see the XUL form (presumably.  None of my browsers support it)

Firefox 4 has [done away with Remote XUL support](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2010/07/21/compatibility-for-firefox-4-time-to-get-started/), BTW, so this isn't a good technology to get to wrapped up in.  (although the same could be said for Notes?  Ouch.)

If you'd like to test your browser using a working example, check out [Jake Howlett's blog post](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20051219) on XUL and follow the link to his demo.

Comment: Sorry, but I not understand how  render 'forms'  and create pages and  **in** Notes.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

The article you're referring to is just showing on how you can add XUL code to a Notes view, which in turn can be then served to a browser by a web-enabled Domino server.

Domino Designer is not suitable for developing XUL code per se, but the Domino architecture is flexible enough to be able to contain the XUL form inside the Domino form and pass it to the browser to render it.

The above answer explains it in detail...